# How can I use a PGP key on Windows to sign/verify and encrypt/decrypt documents?

Tags: windows, encryption, gnupg, pgp

Occasionally I need to encrypt a file, cryptographically sign something, etc. GNU PG and PGP are good tools for this, but how can I get them working on Windows? When I try to search for an installer, I get a lot of different options, and it's not clear which software I actually need! Furthermore, on half the websites it's not even clear which files I need to download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best combination I've been able to find so far is using Gpg4Win and GPGshell. As of August 2012, the current versions and downloads are as follows:

- **Gpg4win**: provides the binaries required for signing and such. This is technically all you need, but the GPGshell makes it a lot easier to manage keys and such, in my opinion. 
  **[Download from gpg4win.org](http://www.gpg4win.org/)**
- **GPGshell**: adds shell extensions (such as right-click menu options and a tray icon) to make using GPG easier. 
  **[Download from jumaros.de](http://www.jumaros.de/rsoft/index.html)**

Comment: GPGshell link is broken, here's an alternative https://www.download82.com/get/download/windows/gpgshell/